# How to mock global variable of List Type?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

I'm trying to mock a global variable which is list type.

Below is the illustration -

This is **first_main.py** -

`url=[]` -- *The result off `url.append(hello.replace(-test',''))` is getting stored here which is in `method_a()` and this is global variable*

```
def method_a():
    url.append(hello.replace(-test',''))
    return something
```

Now, `url=[]` is used in another method.

```
def method_b():
    *Some codes and url=[] is used here in this code.*
    print url
    return True
```

Now, I'm testing `method_b` -

```
@mock.patch('first_main.url')
def test_method_b(self, mock_url_list):
    mock_url_list.return_value.url.return_value = [['a','b'],['c','d']]
    reponse = method_b()
    print response
```

Now, if i put a print statement for `url` which is getting used in `method_b` it should return me the `[['a','b'],['c','d']]` instead of id.

------------**Console**------------

`MagicMock name='url' id='090909090'`

I want return_type in list ie. `[['a','b'],['c','d']]` instead of id.

Thank You

Let me know incase of clarification.

Comment: with `@mock.patch('first_main.url')`, what about change to `mock_url_list.return_value=[['a','b'],['c','d']]`, then you can call `method_a()` inside `method_b` to get url_list.

Comment: please ignore the calling `method_a` part, I was thinking the other post you mentioned.

Comment: :D What you mean "then you can call method_a() inside method_b to get url_list" ? method_a() return type is not url. So, how can I get this global url value ? Do you mean I should run method_a() first then run the actual method_b which I'm trying to test /

Comment: `@mock.path.('first_main.url`, it will mock the `url` in the module `first_main` in the scope of any method you patch, it could a or b, just the code you mentioned is method_b. if you want to test mothod_a, patch it in test_method_a()

Comment: Ok. So under my test method I'm calling  method_a() and it is returning me the response  [['a','b'],['c','d']]. But when I'm calling method_b() which is actual test method there is print statement of url. here, it should print [['a','b'],['c','d']]. But it is returning id which is mentioned in my question. Did I missed something ?

Answer (score 4):

The default behaviour of `mock.patch()` is to substitute the target object with a `MagicMock`. Therefore `print url` will always print the `MagicMock` instance.

However, `mock.patch()` supports a `new_callable` argument which allows you to specify a different type of object. In your case you should be able to supply `list`.

```
@mock.patch('first_main.url', new_callable=list)
def test_method_b(self, mock_url_list):
    mock_url_list.extend([['a','b'],['c','d']])
    reponse = method_b()
    print response
```

Note that in the above example you do not need to use `return_value` because you are not working with a mock. You can manipulate `mock_url_list` as a list.

The `patch` decorator ensures that the original global list is put back the way it was after the test completes.

Answer (score 0):

Providing the answer-

No need to mock. Just import the module and alter the value of the global within setUp():

Refer the link given below-

[Mocking a global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38336090/mocking-a-global-variable/38336234)

Thanks :)

Comment: Do not do this, or you will introduce side-effects for other tests