# How do I test that a global variable is updated as part of a unit test in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest

[Related post on Mocking global variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38336090/mocking-a-global-variable)

```
outgoing.py
table_data = []
def outgoing_data():
    record = *do some stuff*
    table_data.append(record)
```

In a unit test I want to verify that `table_data` is updated. I tried setting it up as shown in the related post but that seems more aimed at using that global variable inside the function by setting its value in the patch. I have been successful in patching the global variable with data to be used in other methods using: `@patch('outgoing.outgoing_data.table_data', [{'action_hist_id': 1, 'page_num': 1, 'row_num': 1}])` as a decorator.

I tried `@patch('outgoing.outgoing_data.table_data', [])` but that didn't work as expected. I was anticipating that a mock would be generated by patch, which it probably was, but I couldn't see it in the debug window to find out if it was called etc.

Let me know if the question isn't clear or needs more info. Thanks in advance.

Comment: my recommendation: don't have a global variable. explicitly pass it to and return it from your functions

Comment: `outgoing.table_data` is the name to patch. The function `outgoing.outgoing_data` doesn't have a function attribute, so creating one that the function won't use doesn't accomplish anything.

Comment: @PaulH i was trying to avoid refactoring the code but that might be the way to go.
@chepner it's possible that I typed out my example code wrong. my intention is to call `outgoing_data` and then test that it updated `table_data`

Comment: I posted my solution to my question just for completeness but in the end I refactored as was suggested by @PaulH

Answer (score 0):

```
@patch('outgoing.table_data')
def my_test(mock_table_data):
    outgoing_data()
    self.assertEqual(expected_result, mock_table_data.method_calls[0][1])
```

This was ran inside a test class, hence the use of `self`. `method_calls[0]` is the first call made to the mock object. `method_calls[0][0]` returns the name of the call, in this case `append` and `method_calls[0][1]` returns the data passed.

[Python docs on Mock.method_calls](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.method_calls)